# I see a attribute in dom <td> element, but unable to retrieve that in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to get the value `width="25%"` from `<td valign="top" width="25%">`, I am starting from a descendant location way below the `<td>`. Possibly there might be more `<td>` elements between my target `<td valign="top" width="25%">`. But I simply cannot get `25%`from the below.

I have tried:

```
var prts = jQuery('.someClassWayBelow').parents('td');

jQuery.each (prts, function () { var css = prts.width(); console.log(css)});
jQuery.each (prts, function () { var css = prts.attr("width"); console.log(css)})
```

I get `664px` or `664` or `undefined`, how do I get a return of `25%`?

Appreciate in advance.

Comment: did you try $(selector).attr('width')?

Comment: best bet is do your own calculation. If it's not set as attribute browser will only return actual dimensions

Comment: Yes, I tried this:  $(selector).attr('width'), without any luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once I made the element under consideration to jQuery object using `$ (this)`, I was able to access methods like `attr()`

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){console.log($("div").attr('width')); });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div width="25%"> </div>
```